# Animate the newly added row in the table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

Is it possible to get IndexPath currently inserting new row into a table. The table data is loaded through the Core Data. The datas are sorted through the sections. 
I would like to make a new added row to the table to be animated as shown in the following picture link.

http://i45.tinypic.com/2ykjj7n.png

Comment: Animating in all the way from the top is not included in the default table animations from apple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following method:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

The code is tested, and will definitely work for you...

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Is this what you want to gather? I am not sure.

```
[yourTableView beginUpdates];
[yourTableView moveRowAtIndex:firstStateIndex toIndex:endStateIndex];
[yourTableView endUpdates];
```

Of course you have to insert the specific row at first so that you can move it afterwards. The animation could happen like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[tblMainView beginUpdates];
[tblMainView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tblMainView endUpdates];
```

Comment: What is that bit after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: supposed to say?